# angular observable to only update it's parent subscriber with multiple components on the page

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have 2 of the same components on the screen. Each component is a table where you can show/hide the columns.

```
<Customtable>
   <child 1>
     ...
      <child 5>
</component 1>

<Customtable>
   <child 1>
     ...
      <child 5>
</component 1>
```

I have some observables where child 5 passes data through a `Observable` which is subscribed from in it's parent.
Child 5 emit subscription -> Customtable.

```
  Export Class ColumnDisplayService {
     visibleColumns = new BehavorSubject<Column[]>([]);

     visibleColumnObservable = this.visibleColumns.asObservable();


    updateVisibleColumns(columns: any[]){
      this.visibleColumns.next(colums);
    }
   }
```

and then the parent component Customtable subscribes as

```
...
this.columnDisplayService.visibleColumnObservable.subscribe(columns => {
  ...set new visible columsn 
});
```

Now this works for when 1 component is on the screen. But when I have 2 components, both are updated. so If I filter `<Customtable>` it filters every other `<Customtable>`. However I only want the child to update it's parent and not the other subscribers. Is this possible with out emitting an event up every child component with `event.emit()`

Comment: Is it possible to show more code? Such as both TypeScript files, parent and child. What you are trying to do seems possible, but I do not have enough to go off of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest providing the `ColumnDisplayService` in your parent component (not in the module nor the root), which will allow you to isolate the instances of `visibleColumnObservable` from each other, and each one of them will be used in this component and its component tree.

```js
@Component({
  //...
  providers: [ColumnDisplayService],
})
export class Customtable {
  constructor(private columnDisplayService: ColumnDisplayService) {
    //...
    // This service will be used in this component and its component tree:
    this.columnDisplayService.visibleColumnObservable.subscribe(columns => {
      ...set new visible columsn 
    });
  }
}
```